# Assigning Array Parameters

Tags: arrays

Attempting to assign array parameters globally

`bytes32[] params;
(params[0], params[1]) = ("p1", "p2");`

results in `ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.`

When moved into a function there is no longer a parser error; but, when the function is called the following error occurs `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode`

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error is because you can't have an assignment outside of a function.

Moving it to a function is correct, but you're writing past the end of the array. `params` starts with a length of 0, but you're trying to write to it.

You can fix that by directly setting the length:

```
params.length = 2;
(params[0], params[1]) = ("p1", "p2");
```

I consider it more straightforward to use `push`:

```
params.push("p1");
params.push("p2");
```

Comment: So we cannot make an assignment to a storage array accept in a function?
Can you explain why

Comment: Correct. That's how most programming languages in the C family work (C/C++/C#/Java, etc.). You can always put that sort of code in the constructor, which is the first executable code in the contract.

Comment: From my understanding, it's incorrect to put _any_ executable code outside of a function, not just assignments (well, in C-family languages there are some exceptions, but let's pretend they don't exist for the sake of not writing an eight-hundred-word simple question). Is that correct?

Comment: @NicHartley I think that might be slightly overbroad... for example `address owner = msg.sender;` probably counts as "executable code" but is allowed outside of a function. I _think_ it's more accurate to say that the only things allowed at the contract level are variable declarations (including initialization) and functions.

Comment: Yeah, variable initialization was one of the "exceptions" I was referring to. Good to know. Thanks!